# My Telerik NumericTextBox is accepting all values. How can i make it to enter only numeric values

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

My Telerik NumericTextBox is accepting all values. 
How can i make it to  enter only numeric values

Comment: What's the exact name of your control? As far as I know they donot have a control called NumericTextBox. Are you referring to RadMaskedNumericInput? RadMaskedNumericInput only accepts numbers by default.You can also use a RadNumericUpDown depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `RadNumericTextBox` , you can change three Type options

```
Currency
Number
Percent
```

The following code works well for me ,

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="ntxtMyNumbers" Type="Number" runat="server"   
LabelWidth="100px" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" Width="100%" />
```